# Use List in Page class Play Framework

Tags: playframework-2.3

In play framework model we can return Page object to render in our view, but Page class can only call from finder object.

```
public static Page<DokumenKeluarFileModel> search(int page, int pageSize, String sortBy, String order, String filter){
    return find.where(filter)
            .orderBy(sortBy + " " + order)
            .findPagingList(pageSize)
            .setFetchAhead(false)
            .getPage(page);
}
```

My question here is Could i use this Page object without using finder object? because i have a list and i want to return it with pagination to the view. Thanks for the advice

Comment: [`Page`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Page.html) is a part of ebean (in the new ebean version you have [`PagedList`](http://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/PagedList.html)). If you want to use `Page`, you will need to implement the `Page` interface to use a list.

Comment: Could you give me the example to use it? or is there any others method for pagination in play framework 2.3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [pagination](https://www.playframework.com/modules/paginate-0.13/home) module exists, but it does not look up to date.

You could try my quick implementation of `Page`:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class ListBackedPage<T> implements Page<T> {

    private final List<T> list;
    private final int pageSize;
    private final int index;

    private ListBackedPage(List<T> list, int pageSize, int index) {
        this.list = list;
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public static <U> Page<U> fromList(List<U> sourceList, int pageSize) {
        return new ListBackedPage(sourceList, pageSize, 0);
    }

    public String getDisplayXtoYofZ(String to, String of) {
        final int start = index * pageSize;
        return String.format("%d %s %d %s %d", 
            start, to, start + pageSize, of, getTotalRowCount());
    }

    public List<T> getList() {
        final int start = index * pageSize;
        final int end = Math.min(start + pageSize, getTotalRowCount());
        System.out.println(start + " - " + end);
        return list.subList(start, end);
    }

    public int getPageIndex() { return index; }

    public int getTotalPageCount() {
        return (int) Math.ceil(list.size() / (double) pageSize);
    }

    public int getTotalRowCount() { return list.size(); }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index >= 0 && index < getTotalPageCount() - 1;
    }

    public boolean hasPrev() {
        return index > 0 && index <= getTotalPageCount();
    }

    public Page<T> next() {
        if (! hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return new ListBackedPage(list, pageSize, index + 1);
    }

    public Page<T> prev() {
        if (! hasPrev())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return new ListBackedPage(list, pageSize, index - 1);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Page %d/%d", index + 1, getTotalPageCount());
    }

}
```

To create a page:

```
List<String> list = java.util.Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
Page<String> page = ListBackedPage.fromList(list, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try to implement this

Comment: Hi peter, i have success implement your class, but i bit confused how to used it on scala, because your class didnt have getPage method unlike Page on the model, could you please explain to me how you used it to navigate between pages?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean. You can get a `Page` using the last line in my answer : `ListBackedPage.fromList(list, 2)`, `page.next()` and `page.prev()` then give you respectively the next and the previous page (if they exist).

Comment: I used page.next, and it change my url to .../Page 2/2, but my routes cannot find that url

Comment: Maybe you can add some code of the route, controller and view you are currently using to your question ?

Comment: You should probably use `page.next.getPageIndex` in your view to create the route for the next page (now it uses the `toString` method). Does your route include a parameter for the page index ?

Answer (score 0):

this is my routes

```
GET     /pencarian                      controllers.Pencarian.index()
POST    /pencarian/search               controllers.Pencarian.search(page:Int ?=0)
```

My Controllers

```
 public static Result search(int page){
    int maxPage = 3;
    Form<PencarianBean> filledform = pencarianForm.bindFromRequest();
    String filter = "";
    String debiturId="";
    String condition="";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    if(!filledform.get().getDebitur().isEmpty()){
        debiturId = DebiturModel.getDebiturId(filledform.get().getDebitur());
        filter = "debitur.cif = "+debiturId;
    }

    if(!filledform.get().getDokumen().isEmpty()){
            if (!filter.equals("")) {
                filter = filter + " and ";
            }
            filter = filter + "namaDokumen.document = \"" +filledform.get().getDokumen()+"\"";
    }

    if(!filledform.get().getNamaDokumen().isEmpty()){
        if (!filter.equals("")){
            filter = filter + " and ";
        }
        filter = filter + "namaDokumen.documentName = \""+filledform.get().getNamaDokumen()+"\"";
    }

    if (filledform.get().getTanggalDokumenStart() != null && filledform.get().getTanggalDokumenEnd() != null){

        if (!filter.equals("")){
            filter = filter + " and ";
        }
        filter = filter + "tanggalDokumen >= \""+format.format(filledform.get().getTanggalDokumenStart()) + "\" and tanggalDokumen <= \"" +format.format(filledform.get().getTanggalDokumenEnd())+"\"";
    }

    if (filledform.get().getJatuhTempoStart() != null && filledform.get().getJatuhTempoEnd() != null){
        if (!filter.equals("")){
            filter = filter + " and ";
        }
        filter = filter + "jatuhTempo >= \""+format.format(filledform.get().getJatuhTempoStart())+ "\" and jatuhTempo <= \"" +format.format(filledform.get().getJatuhTempoEnd())+"\"";
    }

    if(!filledform.get().getMutasi().isEmpty()){
        if (!filter.equals("")){
            filter = filter + " and ";
        }
        if(filledform.get().getMutasi().equals("masuk")){
            filter = filter + "available = true";
        }else{
            if (!filledform.get().getMutasi().equals("keluar")){
                condition = filledform.get().getMutasi();
            }
            filter = filter + "available = false";
        }

    }

    List<PencarianResultBean> pencarianList = getPencarian(DokumenMasukModel.getDokumen(filter, "debitur.debitur", "asc"),condition);

    Page<PencarianResultBean> pencarianPage = ListBackedPage.fromList(pencarianList,maxPage);

    return ok(pencarian.html.pencarianResult.render(pencarianPage,filledform,page));

}
```

I am sorry, i still cant post picture yet. I will use page in /pencarian/search. after clicked next, url will be /pencarian/Page 2/1

Comment: You can not use pagination on a route configured as POST. You would also need all the information from the form you currently use to filter the `PencarianResultBean`s, on the other pagination pages.

Comment: Hi peter, i have changed route to GET, but when i clicked next, its redirect to /pencarian/Page%202/3 which is this routes not in my route. do i miss something ?

Comment: You need to pass the `Page.next.getPageIndex` as a parameter not the `Page.next.toString`. But it is difficult to help you without the code of your view.

Answer (score 0):

This is my view

```
@(documentList: com.avaje.ebean.Page[PencarianResultBean], pencarianForm: Form[PencarianBean])
@import helper._


@body("Pencarian"){
<div class="container">
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <table class="table table-hover" style="width: 800px;">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Debitur</th>
                <th>Nama Dokumen</th>
                <th>Nomor</th>
                <th>Tanggal Dokumen</th>
                <th>Jatuh Tempo</th>
                <th>Pemilik</th>
                <th>Lokasi</th>
                <th>Luas</th>
                <th>Nilai</th>
                <th>Asli/Copy</th>
                <th>Ada/Tidak</th>
                <th>Nomor Bast</th>
                <th>Tanggal</th>
                <th>Keterangan</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @for(doc <- documentList.getList){
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @doc.getDebitur
                </td>
                <td>
                    @doc.getNamaDokumen
                </td>
                <td>
                    @doc.getNomor
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if(doc.getTanggalDokumen == null){
                    <em>-</em>
                    }else{
                    @doc.getTanggalDokumen.format("dd/MM/yyyy")
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if(doc.getJatuhTempo == null){
                    <em>-</em>
                    }else{
                    @doc.getJatuhTempo.format("dd/MM/yyyy")
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @doc.getPemilik
                </td>
                <td>
                    @doc.getLokasi
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="autonumber">@doc.getLuas</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="autonumber">@doc.getNilai</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if(doc.getAsli == true){
                    A
                    }else{
                    C
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if(doc.getAvailable == true){
                    A
                    }else{
                    T
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @doc.getNomorBast
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if(doc.getTanggal == null){
                    <em>-</em>
                    }else{
                    @doc.getTanggal.format("dd/MM/yyyy")
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @doc.getKeterangan
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="pagination">
    @if(documentList.hasPrev) {
    <li class="prev">
        <a href="@documentList.prev">&larr; Previous</a>
    </li>
    } else {
    <li class="prev disabled">
        <a>&larr; Previous</a>
    </li>
    }
    <li class="current">
        <a>Displaying @documentList.getDisplayXtoYofZ(" to "," of ")</a>
    </li>
    @if(documentList.hasNext) {
    <li class="next">
        <a href="@documentList.next">Next &rarr;</a>
    </li>
    } else {
    <li class="next disabled">
        <a>Next &rarr;</a>
    </li>
    }
</ul>

@form(routes.Pencarian.index()){
<input type="hidden" name ="mutasi" value="@pencarianForm("mutasi").value">
<input type="hidden" name ="debitur" value="@pencarianForm("debitur").value">
<input type="hidden" name ="dokumen" value="@pencarianForm("dokumen").value">
<input type="hidden" name ="namaDokumen" value="@pencarianForm("namaDokumen").value">
<input type="hidden" name ="tanggalDokumenStart" value="@pencarianForm("tanggalDokumenStart").value">
<input type="hidden" name ="tanggalDokumenEnd" value="@pencarianForm("tanggalDokumenEnd").value">
<input type="hidden" name ="jatuhTempoStart" value="@pencarianForm("jatuhTempoStart").value">
<input type="hidden" name ="jatuhTempoEnd" value="@pencarianForm("jatuhTempoEnd").value">

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info cusbutton">Cancel</button>
</div>
}
```

}